# Picocli: is it possible to calculate Option default value with help of some other Autowired field?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, picocli

I want to implement the following logic of Option default value calculation

```
@Command(name = "test-command")
public class TestCommand implements Callable {
    
    @Autowired
    DefaultValueUtils utils;
    
    @ArgGroup
    EntityGroup functions = new EntityGroup();
    
    class EntityGroup {
        @Option(names = "--function1", defaultValue = "true")
        boolean function1 = utils.isFunction1();

        @Option(names = "--function2", defaultValue = "true")
        boolean function2 = utils.isFunction2();
    }
    
    ...
}
```

I have 2 boolean options - function1 and function2; if they are not provided their default values are specified in some other place. But if options provided, I need to override values with provided ones.
One more problem is in following logic:

if none of them provided - default values should be calculated;
If one of them provided - only provided one is true, not provided false;
If both provided - both are true

How can I implement this?

This current block of the code is failing because utils is null during EntityGroup instantiation.

Comment: How do you setup your application? Did you use pico cli springboot integration https://github.com/remkop/picocli/blob/main/picocli-spring-boot-starter/README.md

Comment: Yes, of course I use. I debugged and it seems like options default values initialization happen before injection of @Autowired fields. So at that point of time I got NPE